# Translate a Excel Range to a row/col

Tags: excel, vsto

I have looked all over but can't find an answer to this...

Quite simply put I have a VSTO Excel 2007 project that I want to be able to translate a cell (e.g. "A1") to integers row 1, column 1.

Does anybody know of a built in method for this or do I have to write my own parser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could;

```
r = Range("AP100")
```

then `r.row` and `r.column` will return their numeric index.